# Multiple panes in a Tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 panes in the  `<tabs id="mainTabs"`

```
<pane title="Name search"> and  <pane title="List search">
```

When I try to see this on web it shows both the pans as single (merged).

Can anyone figure out what is wrong?

[image]

```html
<div id="container"  ng-controller="graphAppCtrl">
<div id="graph-container"><div id="notice" class="hidden">layout in progress...</div></div>
    <div id="search-container" ng-app="graphApp" ng-controller="graphAppCtrl">
        <tabs id="mainTabs">
            <pane title="Name search">
                <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
                <button ng-click="myFunction()">Search</button>
                <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped"   fixed-table-headers="scrollable-area">
                    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="false" > </dir-pagination-controls>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Index  </td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>ID</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr dir-paginate="x in names | object2Array |orderBy : 'NAME' |itemsPerPage:7"  >
                            <td>{{ $index + 1 }} </td>
                            <td>{{ x.NAME }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.ID }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>    
                </table>
            </pane> 
            <pane title="List search">
                    <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
                        <INPUT type="checkbox" ng-model="keywordbox" />Check box to search Name: <BR/>  
                        <INPUT type="text" ng-show="keywordbox" ng-model="inputbox" size="30"  VALUE=""/>
                        <INPUT type="checkbox" ng-model="querybox" />Check box to query:
                        <br/>Enter Query: <BR/>
                        <INPUT type="text"  ng-model="inputbox2" size="30"  VALUE=""/>
                        <INPUT type="button" NAME="button" Value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)"/><BR/> <BR/>
                    </FORM>
            </pane>
        </tabs>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found out that the pans dissapear due to controller of angularJS which is :

```
var angularjsapp = angular.module('graphApp', []);
angularjsapp.controller('graphAppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.names= {0:{'Name':'John','Country':'albania'}};
        //$scope.reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you find any mistake in the given code ?

Comment: @Mosh Feu I have tried to used bootsrap link that you gave . I am having some trouble can you please have a look at the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/zohairzohair4/6gjrhsct/)

Comment: What exactly the problem? Maybe it will be better if you will update your question and notify me in a comment so it will help to other people.

Comment: The probelm is that I want to have 2 separate Tabs for different tasks. This is not happening. I found out out that I have a angularJS controller in my javascript which if removed shows the 2 tabs that I want.

Comment: @Mosh Feu I tried to implemet in bootstrap but then the angularJS functionalities doesnt work .

Comment: Can you post an updated jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mosh Feu https://jsfiddle.net/zohairzohair4/v0y7t0mL/ .

Comment: You can see a demo of accordion [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) Make sure you have the all refferences and you have no errors in the console.